# AdWords: how to optimize for only one or two conversion types?

Tags: google-ads

I've checked: "Use my conversion tracking data and bids to optimize for conversions".

I have 3 conversion types, but one of these is not relevant in terms of the optimization.

How do I get AdWords to focus on one or two relevant conversion(s)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of conversions:

**Conversions (1-per-click)**

**Conversions (many-per-click)**

You can select the one that is most useful for you by going to **Tools and Analysis > Conversions > Settings > Edit Settings**

If you would like to delete one or more conversions go to **Tools and Analysis > Conversions** and then click on the green spot next to the check box of the conversion you want to delete and select **"Deleted"**

You can also add new conversions by going to **Tools and Analysis > Conversions > +Conversion**

Here are some links that could be interesting for you:

[Understanding conversion tracking](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722022?hl=en)

[Complete Guide to Conversion Tracking in AdWords](http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2013/08/13/adwords-conversion-tracking-guide)